# How to tell xargs to unpack tar into certain directory

Tags: find, tar, xargs

I wrote my first script which goes:

```
find /media/temp/test -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n*.tar.gz' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" " | xargs tar -xvpf
```

I would like to find latest modified file which is .tar.gz and then unpack it into certain directory not the /media/temp/test

Comment: Does the `find` call produce the output you want? If so then you should provide example output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your command works correctly,
you can just replace the last part

```
xargs tar -xvpf
```

with

```
(cd /certain/directory; xargs tar -xvpf)
```

and the tar command will be executed from this directory.
This is a common useful 'trick' for executing commands relative to another directory.

Note this only works in this because your tar file name (in this case, the output from the find command) is an absolute path.  If it were a relative pathname, then the 'cd' above wouldn't work.

`tar` already has an argument you can use:

```
 -C directory
         In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the following files.  In x mode, change directories after opening
         the archive but before extracting entries from the archive.
```

So, you could also have the last part be

```
xargs tar -C /certain/directory -xvpf
```

Check and test your version of tar; there are subtle differences between platforms (you don't specify which unix variant you are using).
Hopefully the pathnames within your archive are relative also.

Comment: thank you for help! I missed the -C switch. Now my script is working. Thank you very much.